# Why does no OOM is thrown when I enlarge the xms and xmx arguments

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

Here is the code which is applied in order to simulate a circumstance that will throw OOM:

```
public class OOMTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        heapOOM();
    }

    public static void heapOOM()     {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        while(true) {
            list.add(new Object());
        }
    }
}
```

When I apply arguments as below, in which `xmx` and `xms` is lower than 18M, it works just fine and will throw OOM:

```
-Xms18M -Xmx18M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

But when the `xmx` and `xms` is larger than 19M, the project will just run without stopping, with memory fluctuating around 39MB in the task manager.

Could anyone give me some idea on why this phenomenon happens? Thanks a lot!

**P.S.** When I change `new Object()` to `new String("test")` or `new Long(2)`, it just works fine. Why?

Comment: Could be the JIT optimizes this away? What happens if you run your program with the `-Xint` flag? Don't think this would be GC because each created `Object` should have a reference in `list`...

Comment: Please try replacing `new Object()` with `new String("Test")`.

Comment: There should be reference in the `List` for each Object, right? Thus it should not be `GC`ed. Is my understanding correct? @user3580294

Comment: @Judking That's what I'm thinking, and that's why I was guessing that this could be the work of the JIT compiler. What happens if you run that code with the `-Xint` flag?

Comment: Amazing! It works! Could you give me some more detailed explanations on this problem? You know, as I said above, I think whatever the `Object` is, there should be a reference in the list for each `Object`, I don't know whether it is correct or not for this understanding. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: @Judking Just confirming, `-Xint` caused the program to throw an OOM error?

Comment: Nope, it's the same with `-Xint`. @user3580294

Comment: A `new Object` is really just a reference to anything (in Java). It's very, very optimized. It also doesn't really have any state. Where as a `String` also occupies the intern cache, this is why `new String()` is such a bad idea...

Comment: I've googled on `potential reference`, but find nothing. What do you mean by **potential**? You mean that essentially the `Object`s in the list are all the same, thus they're actually just one object in the heap? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Try this `for (;;) System.out.println(new Object());`, you'll notice that the JVM can address a lot of memory. In fact, if you don't actually address anything.... it might seem to address all the memory.

Comment: What do you mean by addressing a lot of memory? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: What do you think a `new Object` is?

Comment: Allocating a space in heap for `Object` instance, and storing the reference, which points to the above `Object` instance, in the `List` instance. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Alright, an [OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) is also an Object. If you've allocated all of the available java.lang.Object references the JVM can't throw it. The JIT optimizes references, and unreachable references are eligible for GC. A new `java.lang.Object` is just a (potentially unreachable) reference, even if it's in a List. Especially if that List (also) isn't reachable.

Comment: So what is the difference between `Object` and `String`? Cuz `String` itself is a subclass of `Object` class. And I've tried to define a class named `OOMObject` whose body is empty, it works just the same as the `Object` class. Why wouldn't the JIT treat the `String` instance as a (potentially unreachable) reference just like the `Object` does? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Strings have immutable state, and a `new String` also takes up space in the intern pool. This all varies by JVM implementation, and isn't the sort of thing you can accurately measure anyway. What problem are you actually trying to solve? How does this help you solve it?

Comment: you mean that the `String` instance will be put in the intern pool when it is created by `new String` even without calling `intern()` method? I'm just curious about the phonomenon in my issue, I don't know why the size of `xms` and `xmx` will affect whether there's a OOM or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54579/discussion-between-judking-and-elliott-frisch).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check whether it is generating the same reference. One way to check is to Instantiate a Set and and add the ArrayList into the set. Post that you could take a count. In case for some reason the jvm is not creating a new instance the size of the set and the list would differ. 
Worth checking this to understand whether a new instance is created in the loop or not. I tried the same using java 1.7 and got the Outofmemory exception.